# Why isn't this while condition reevaluated?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, loops, while-loop

I have two while conditions, one inside the other, with booleans to control them. Basically, one is for terminating a share and the other is to listen for a connection. A user can select to disable a share, and in this case, the server stops listening but it won't terminate. If a user selects to terminate then both booleans are set to false and the cycle ends.

This is my code:

```
        public void run() {
            while (!terminate) {  
                while (listening) {
                    try {
                        // accept connection -> create a new thread for each client
                        ClientServerShareInstance clientServerShareInstance = new ClientServerShareInstance(serverSocket.accept(), ui);
                        Thread clientServerThread = new Thread(clientServerShareInstance);
                        clientSockets.add(clientServerShareInstance);
                        connectedClients++;
                        clientServerThread.start();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void closeAllClientConnections() {
            for (Iterator it = clientSockets.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                ClientServerShareInstance clientServerShareInstance = (ClientServerShareInstance) it.next();
                clientServerShareInstance.closeAllConnections();
                it.remove();
            }
            try {
                this.serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {}
            this.setActive(false);
            this.connectedClients = 0;
        }


        public void openConnection() {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber, 0, Inet4Address.getLocalHost());
                setActive(true);
            } catch (IOException ex) {}
        }
    }
```

The `closeAllClientConnections()` method disables a share (does not terminate it), and the `openConnection()` reenables that share.

The problem is, if I disable a share, it should just loop the `terminate` while cicle indefinitely, testing the value of `listening`. When I set `listening` to `true`, it should re-enter that second while loop and start listening again, because I do open the server socket (although it's not related to that, I'm just saying it has to be initialized again because I close it when I disable the share). However, after disabling, it never renters the `listening` loop, even when `openConnection()` is called.

Anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: `setActive(...)` sets the value of `listening`?

Comment: No, they're just declared as regular private booleans inside my class. I didn't use volatile because I thought objects were shared between multiple threads and I didn't require locks because it's not a complex operation where multiple threads are 'fighting' for access at the same time.

Comment: @Gray Yes, it does. It's just a setter for that variable.

Comment: I've moved my comments to an answer.

Comment: How about formatting your code properly...

Comment: @Bohemian: It's formatted properly. It's just missing the topmost method's head.

Comment: @Bohemian Exactly, it's inside the run() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not enough code shown to show any errors.  But here are some comments that might help.

- Both the `shutdown` and `listening` booleans need to be `volatile`. Any fields shared between threads need to be somehow synchronized otherwise changes to their values will not be seen by other threads.
- `serverSocket` will also need to be `volatile` since it seems to be created by the caller of `openConnection()` but consumed in the `while` loop. You might consider just setting active to the true in `openConnection()` and have `serverSocket` managed entirely by the accept thread.
- `clientSockets` looks to be a collection.  That will need to be a synchronized connection since, again, it looks like it is accessed by multiple threads.  Again, a better pattern would be for the `closeAllClientConnections()`  call to *just* set a boolean and the thread itself would do the closing.  That removes any race conditions around using the collections, etc..
- Looks to be that if you are `! terminating` that your accept thread will spin.  At the very least you should put some `Thread.sleep(100)` or something to slow it down.   A wait/notify would even be better.

It is important to realize that it is not *just* about what happens "at the same time" in a threaded program.  It is also about memory caching. The accept thread could have added something to the `clientSockets` `ArrayList1` a minute ago and another thread may not see those changes if the list is not synchronized somehow. Even worse is the prospect that certain portions of the `ArrayList` may have been updated in memory but not others which might cause an exception.  To get a synchronized collection, you should create your `ArrayList` like:

```
List<...> clientSockets = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<...>());
```

Sounds like you should read some of the documentation about why synchronization is necessary:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: serverSocket is created there, but it's mostly a re-instantiation, because it initializes first in the run() method (upon first creating that share).

Comment: Reinstantiation still needs to be synchronized @Lovato.  Any changes to any fields need to be synchronized if they are changed by multiple threads.  Also, there is a lot of complexity around constructor optimizations that may cause the socket to be constructed but not fully initialized.  You should avoid constructing it in one thread and consuming it in another if you can.

Comment: clientSockets is a ArrayList of client sockets. When I disable a share, I have to close any clients connected to that share, so I store them in a collection, call the closeAllConnections() and that closes all connections for each client and then remove them from the list.

Comment: I understand this @Lovato but because the accept thread is also adding to the `ArrayList`, any time you use the list you need to have it be in a `synchronized` block.  I've added some required reading to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, kind sir. This solved my issue, using `volatile` fixed that. The `ArrayList` is a public static collection, which other threads need to access to perform remove operations (only this thread adds anything). However, only one thread at a time can ever add or remove an object (because it's a JTable, and a button that provides that enable/disabling feature).

Comment: And yes, when I disable a share it just does a infinite loop, which is why I had the idea of using a `Semaphore` with initial value 0 if `listening` is false, so that it blocks immediately and waits until the openConnection() releases it.

Comment: Dude.  You aren't getting it.  It is not _just_ about what happens at the same time, it is about memory caching.  The accept thread could have added something to the `ArrayList` a minute ago and another thread may not see it.  Even worse is the prospect that certain portions of the `ArrayList` are updated but not others which might cause an exception.  You should create your `ArrayList` like: Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<...>());`

Comment: @Lovato Please take 30 minutes at least and read the link I posted.  It is critical otherwise you are writing buggy code that may work sometimes but will fail spectacularly others.